# How to change the default function of Arrow key in JTabbed Panel?

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings, jtabbedpane, key-events

I created the Tab panel which is having 3 tabs, and in each tab I'm displaying chart.
My problem is I want to use arrow key to move a chart back and forth.
But when I pressed arrow it switches the tab.

How I can remove this default behavior of Arrow key of swiching tabs?

Answer (score 5):

You have to unregister keybinding.

For example:

```
tabComponent.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"), "none");
tabComponent.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"), "none");
```

You may want to take a look at this [How to use KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).